# find base image or ''source in docker hub'' for an image in local

Tags: docker, dockerhub

The project I am working have its docker images built from

```
FROM java:8-jre
```

Now I am writing a new service and though I can also make java:8-jre base image for my service. But I wanted to find out from where it was taken at the first place. As on docker hub I see only openjdk or oracle one is available.

Also if I do like below it is downloaded from docker hub (I guess, As I tried on my local as well), But cant see it on dockerHub(why?)

```
docker pull java:8-jre
```

**Is there any way, I can search this image at docker hub or find its source with something like below -**

```
docker image inspect java:8-jre
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image belongs to the **official java repository**, which is **deprecated** in favor of [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) repository.

Accessing this repo will redirect you to the openjdk page.

But you can have a glimpse of java repo page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170415032751/https://hub.docker.com/_/java/).

You can still find the Dockerfile for your image [here](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/ac78a119a294925b60c8fe4e64c79abab1dd8dbf/8-jre/Dockerfile).

Comment: this looks to be nice, means it is there in docker-hub(for backward compatibility), but not shown to favor openjdk use. thanks (y)

Answer (score 1):

Information which you need will be available in `Dockerfile` for that particular image.

I didn't find any image with name `java:8-jre` in docker hub.

Closest which I found was

https://hub.docker.com/r/fiadliel/java8-jre/

To see steps of `Dockerfile` for that Image build try this

```
docker image history --no-trunc image_name > image_history
```

Comment: this https://hub.docker.com/r/fiadliel/java8-jre/ is clearly different. From history too we cant find much about its place in dockerhub